# How to unpack a list of colons and NumPy Nones to index an array?

Tags: numpy, indexing, argument-unpacking

I am writing a program that will have an arbitrary number of `:` and `None` in arbitrary locations of an n-dimensional NumPy array. Therefore, I want a way to unpack these `:` and `None` axis operators into the `[]` that indexes an array and auto-populates certain axes according to where the `:` and `None` are. According to Pylance:

> Unpack operator in subscript requires Python 3.11 or newerPylance

However, while using Python 3.11, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/.../quant.py", line 261, in <module>
    print(arr[*lhs_axes] + arr2[None,None,:])
          ~~~^^^^^^^^^^^
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

Current code:

```
import numpy as np
if __name__ == "__main__":
    lhs_ind, rhs_ind = 'ij', 'k'
        
    lhs_axes = [':' for i in lhs_ind]
    lhs_axes.append(None)

    arr1 = np.ones((2,2))
    arr2 = np.ones(2)
    print(arr1[*lhs_axes] + arr2[None,None,:])
```

Comment: Note that I tried using the string 'None' instead of None, but it returned the same error.

Answer (score 1):

A `':'` string and the `:` are very different things. `:` is equivalent to `slice(None)`.

Use a `slice` and `tuple`:

```
import numpy as np
if __name__ == "__main__":
    lhs_ind, rhs_ind = 'ij', 'k'
 
    lhs_axes = [slice(None) for i in lhs_ind]
    lhs_axes.append(None)
    arr1 = np.ones((2,2))
    arr2 = np.ones(2)
    print(arr1[tuple(lhs_axes)] + arr2[None,None,:])
```

Output:

```
[[[2. 2.]
  [2. 2.]]

 [[2. 2.]
  [2. 2.]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I make a list with `slice` and `None` objects:

```
In [44]: idx = [slice(None),slice(None),None]
In [45]: idx
Out[45]: [slice(None, None, None), slice(None, None, None), None]
```

I can make a tuple from the list with:

```
In [46]: tuple(idx)
Out[46]: (slice(None, None, None), slice(None, None, None), None)
```

or with unpacking - in a tuple context (a list context as well):

```
In [47]: (*idx,)
Out[47]: (slice(None, None, None), slice(None, None, None), None)
```

For indexing, the tuple works fine:

```
In [48]: arr = np.ones((2,3,4),int)    

In [50]: arr[tuple(idx)].shape
Out[50]: (2, 3, 1, 4)
```

The unpacking that you try to use is a 3.11 addition:

```
In [51]: arr[*idx].shape
  Input In [51]
    arr[*idx].shape
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

But it isn't needed if you provide a tuple.  `arr[1,2,3]` is the same as `arr[(1,2,3)]`.  `arr[[1,2,3]]` can be problematic.  Strictly speaking that's indexing the first dimension, same as `arr[np.array([1,2,3])]`.  But for historical reasons, sometimes such a list is treated as a tuple.  In which case you'll get a future warning:

```
FutureWarning: Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing is deprecated; 
use `arr[tuple(seq)]` instead of `arr[seq]`. In the future this will be interpreted 
as an array index, `arr[np.array(seq)]`, which will result either in an error or a different result.
```